# Entity Framework stored procedure result

Tags: .net, entity-framework, stored-procedures, join, entity-framework-5

I can have stored procedure return a collection of existing entities. How do I join/include other entities in this scenario? Is this even possible?

Comment: Do you have some code of what you did so far? I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: "Edit function import" in my .edmx datamodel allows for the definition of the return type of a stored procedure. I can select an entity (representing a table) which I want to return. Consider this: `sp_GetProducts()` returns a collection of `Product`. How do I _include_ or _join_ the `ProductCategory` entity when returning data from the `sp_getProducts()` procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something along these lines suffice?

```
var joinResult = (from product in dbContext.sp_GetProducts()
                 join cat in dbContext.ProductCategory on product.catID equals cat.ID
                 select new { product = product, category = cat }).ToList();
```

Alternatively you could do the joining inside of the store procedure.